# How to save the content of flowDocument in PDF and Word?

Tags: wpf, pdf, flowdocument, xps, doc

Is there a way of saving the content of flowdocument control in .pdf and .doc format not just XPS?

**Not a 3rd party control**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

.DOC / .DOCX was achieved using [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx)

.PDF was achieved by converting [.DOC to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334711/wpf-flowdocument-to-pdf)

Comment: This is misleading answer as it requires Office to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am author of XamlToPDF Library, however it is free for commercial as well as non commercial use.

http://xamltopdf.codeplex.com/

It saves Flow document to PDF with images, tables etc.

Comment: XamlPdfWriter seems to take the FlowDocument as a string to generate the PDF. How can I convert a FlowDocument object to it's xml string representation? or is there a way to pass the FlowDocument directly?

Comment: Answer to myself: `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save` does the trick.